# Aurdino coding to control a motor

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

```
//Motor A
const int motorpin1  = 6; // Pin  6 of L293
const int motorpin2  = 9;  // Pin  3 of L293

void setup() {
  pinMode(motorpin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorpin2, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    char incomingByte = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
    if(incomingByte=='a'){
      digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorpin2, HIGH);

      Serial.println("one way");
    }
    else if(incomingByte=='s'){
      digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(motorpin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);

      Serial.println("other way");
    }
    else{
      digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

If we input a in the serial monitor the motor should rotate in one direction and if we input s the motor should rotate in another direction but it is not happening the motor is idle but i get the output like this:

```
a
one way


s
other way
```

There is no problem with hardware connections.

Could you please help me with this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this delay (200ms) OK for this step motor? I wonder if this is not too little for the motor to stop.

Comment: @campescassiano I tried increasing the delay but it doesnt make any diffrence

Comment: Is `pin 1` of the L293 enabled? I mean, it should be set to `HIGH`.

Comment: @campescassiano thank you,there was a small logic error I corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments in your code, you are conecting `arduino-pin-6` to the `l293-pin-6`, and `arduino-pin-9` to the `l293-pin-3`.

According to [this](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/26885/TI/L293.html) datasheet, the control pins in L293 are: `2`, `7`, `10`, `15`. So, I believe you are connecting it wrong. Also the pulses are being done in the wrong order (from `HIGH` to `LOW` and so on).

This should be the correct code (**please look at the comments in the code**):

```c
//Motor A
const int motorpin1  = 6; // Pin  7 of L293
const int motorpin2  = 9;  // Pin  2 of L293
const int motorenablepin = 10; // Pin 1 of L293

void setup() {
  pinMode(motorpin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorpin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorenablepin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorenablepin, HIGH); // we can let it enabled
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
void loop(){

  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    char incomingByte = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
    if(incomingByte=='a'){
      digitalWrite(motorpin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);

      Serial.println("one way");
    }
    else if(incomingByte=='s'){
      digitalWrite(motorpin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);

      Serial.println("other way");
    }
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);
  }
}
```

Please note that I added the `motorenablepin` that was missing. It must be conected to the `l293-pin-1`.

Also, since the `LOW` and `LOW` states are common to the code, you can simplify it as I did.

Comment: pin 2 and 7 are the input pins..how can we connect motor to input pin?? referf this link for pinout ```https://lastminuteengineers.com/l293d-dc-motor-arduino-tutorial```

Comment: The `pin-2`  and `pin-7` of the L293 are the ones used to connect to the Arduino. Please look at [this](https://fabacademy.org/archives/2015/eu/students/papaleo.alessandro/project/img/l293d.jpg) image to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There was small mistake in the logic:

```
if(incomingByte=='a'){
     digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
digitalWrite(motorpin2, HIGH);//changed to high
   delay(10000);
digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);//changed to low
Serial.println("one way");
   }
   else if(incomingByte=='s'){

digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);
digitalWrite(motorpin2, HIGH);//changed to high
delay(2000);
digitalWrite(motorpin1, LOW);//changed to low
digitalWrite(motorpin2, LOW);
```